# Tree SHAP plus XGBoost - list must be integers or slices, not tuple

Tags: python, pandas, xgboost

I have been trying to figure out how to use tree SHAP to further evaluate my XGBoost classifiers. I am running into some issues with the data that has to be user error. I don't understand what from the input is causing this...

Input: shap.force_plot(explainer.expected_value, shap_values[0,:], X.iloc[0,:])

Setup:

```
import shap
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as pl

# load JS visualization code to notebook
shap.initjs()
```

Config for explainer and shap_values:

```
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X)
```

Generate Display:

```
shap.force_plot(explainer.expected_value, shap_values[0,:], X.iloc[0,:])
```

**Error**:

It is something going on with the generation of shap_values. I don't understand what would be wrong with the X (data frame) I am passing opposed to the one they get using the boston data set in their example.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-dd74c29cab4f> in <module>
----> 1 shap.force_plot(explainer.expected_value, shap_values[0,:], mean_data.iloc[0,:])

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Output of:

```
print(explainer.expected_value)
print(shap_values) # Is a list as Robin Niel thought
```

[-0.84587, 1.0577996, 1.1045177]

[array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       ...,
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       ...,
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32), array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       ...,
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)]

From the README: https://github.com/slundberg/shap/blob/master/README.md

```
import xgboost
import shap

# load JS visualization code to notebook
shap.initjs()

# train XGBoost model
X,y = shap.datasets.boston()
model = xgboost.train({"learning_rate": 0.01}, xgboost.DMatrix(X, label=y), 100)

# explain the model's predictions using SHAP
# (same syntax works for LightGBM, CatBoost, scikit-learn and spark models)
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X)

# visualize the first prediction's explanation (use matplotlib=True to avoid Javascript)
shap.force_plot(explainer.expected_value, shap_values[0,:], X.iloc[0,:])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What types are shap_values ? It says in the doc :

> For models with a single output this returns a matrix of SHAP values (# samples x # features). Each row sums to the difference between the model output for that sample and the expected value of the model output (which is stored in the expected_value attribute of the explainer when it is constant). For models with vector outputs this returns a list of such matrices, one for each output.

If you are in the second case, it could be a list (so python native from what I understand) and therefore cannot use numpy indexing as you're doing (shap_values[0,:]). If that's the case, I think you simple need to do shap_value[0]. Let me know if that solved your problem.

Comment: You were right. shap_values is a list. I updated the question with the output of expected_value and shap_values

Comment: As I told you in my answer, since it's a list of numpy arrays, you can just replace shap_values[0,:] by shap_values[0] I think.

Comment: Yeah I did try that. I get errors doing that also. I am wondering if it has something to do with my use case and the data/classes I am trying to generate. I obviously have no idea.

Comment: Robin was right, it was the output type given i am doing classification